# MMX Invalid floating point operation

Tags: c++, assembly, c++builder-6, mmx

Using C++ Builder 6 and trying to run this code

```
  __int64 m64_1 = 1424115525456;
  __int64 m64_2 = 2222222222222;
  __int64 m64_3 = 1111111111111;


    __asm movq mm1, m64_1
    __asm paddd mm1, m64_2
    __asm movq m64_3, mm1
```

[image: Getting and exception]

but I don't execute division by zero.
What about this error

Comment: If you MMX you must also EMMS

Comment: I don't see where it shows that one of those instructions causes the exception.  Why do you think it is there?

Comment: @wallyk when i debug it. i go across __asm lines and crashed into 'Memo1->Text = "assemble"';

Comment: @harold my task is multiply to arrays using mmx. Do you think EMMS will help me?

Comment: **Project Project1.exe raised exception calss EInvalidOp with message "Invalid floating point operation. Process stopped"**

Comment: EMMS does not help per se, but it is required in order to make subsequent code safe. Not EMMS-ing leaves the FPU stack in a state that makes almost all FPU code crash instantly. The error caused by that should really be FPU stack overflow but maybe the dialog does not distinguish

Comment: @harold awesome. i typed `__asm emms` after mmx commands and it work!Thank you

Comment: You should probably use SSE2 for new code, instead of MMX.  `emms` is slow-ish, and in recent CPUs (Skylake), the MMX versions of many vector instructions can't run on as many execution ports.  (i.e. CPU designers don't care as much about MMX anymore, because it's obsolete.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just type `__asm emms` after your mmx commands 
like that:

```
__asm movq mm1, m64_1;
__asm paddd mm1, m64_2;
__asm movq m64_3, mm1;
__asm emms
```

Comment: You should really make this a community wiki answer since it's actually @harold's answer.